# What motor to use for reciprocating (reversive) movement

Tags: motor, stepper-motor, mechanism

I want to make a copy of this machine [Fisher Price Soothing Motions™ Glider](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=16x-_9pcWXU) and I'm wondering what motor to use? Simple DC motor with appropriate gearbox (slow rpm) or stepper motor?

[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=KvlVKIuXGuI) is another instance of this idea.

Comment: This is a fairly broad question, because many motors might be suited to this task.

Comment: I should remember to look back at this question when we decide to have a baby!

Comment: You would need a fairly powerful motor for this application and I would also be concerned about safety if you build your own.

Comment: @GuySirton I completely agree with the safety part. But the powerful one is relative. Even that, it needs just to overcome the inertia. Depending on the rotor, the inertia of the rotor could help the motor in the more requiring force travels. This with the motion being relatively slow, would let a fraction of hp to do the work. But, as the motor is supposed to run at continuous duty, I would be more concerned on thermostat, colling the motor, that is, safety.

Comment: @MarianPaździoch seems that the first one has linear motion, if so you should have to project the sliding mechanism too. The second one already shows the mechanism (reciprocating), with a DC brushed-motor and gear-box.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Note the video shows a fairly high acceleation of a fairly high load (multiple kilograms at least).  This isn't an RC car motor in there, it's something that can chew up your fingers...  (an appropriately geared RC car motor might do that too though but this is bigger...)

Comment: @GuySirton well its approximately 1 travel per second. Depending on the crank mechanism this would be 0.5RPS. Small DC brushed motors normally go to 1000RPM easy under small load (thats so generic anyway), so a reduction of 1:34 can be used. Consider a motor with a stall torque of 1kgf/cm then we have 34kgf/cm. With a 10 cm arm, that is 3,4Kg of linear force on the more fast rotation period.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento Your arm would need to be much longer to get this stroke, right?  You need to take into account the mechanism you use to translate the rotary motion into linear motion.  By your argument we can move any linear mass with any acceleration as long as we make the arm short enough...

Comment: @GuySirton I don't think it needs to be much longer than that. If we assume the crank shaft to be at the same plane as the linear axis of motion, with a 10 cm arm we have 20 cm travel, I don't know how much the baby needs :) Anyway my example don't leave into consideration gearing losses, but it take a 18W DC-Brushes motor in the best efficiency as an example (stall torque is more than 3Kgf/cm), really a small motor for this (opinion based).

Comment: Well other thing to consider is noisy, otherwise the music should be on all the time :)

Comment: @GuySirton `By your argument we can move any linear mass with any acceleration as long as we make the arm short enough` I don't know from where you get that. My argument is objective about the stroke length, torque and force, and speed, no place I say the stroke can be any length with the same force.

Comment: @Diego C Nascimento: noise shouldn't be such a problem, in fact it can even help to lull the baby

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento But the force that a crank puts out isn't constant, it depends on the angle of the motor.  I think it'd be easier to see if we go through the calculation with a screw drive.

Comment: @GuySirton if the mechanism is designed the way I said, the less force and more fast will be at center of travel, as it produces a sinusoidal like motion. The calc are for these rotation moment.

Comment: @DiegoCNascimento It seemed to me the stroke was longer and the required acceleration was higher but sounds like Marian did find a relatively small motor in the device as per his comment below...  I wonder what motor specifically that was.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A DC or AC gearmotor is all you need. If you're asking about a stepper because of the change in direction, you can use a crank shaft mechanism to convert motion from rotary to reciprocating linear like the one in the above image:

[image: a crank mechanism]

Comment: Reciprocating motion - I was looking for that term, thanks. And by the way I've bought and disassembled "Fisher Price Soothing Motions™ Glider" - there is simple crankshaft mechanism with small toy-looking DC motor (cylinder shaped, ~3cm diameter, 3cm height)

Comment: @lyndon your answer would be a lot nicer with a drawing (or a picture) of such a mechanism...  Maybe Marian could contribute a picture of the actual mechanism from the device?

Comment: I'm positive that I was able to upload a .gif animation to electronics.stackexchange.com before. Did StackExchange stop accepting gifs? Animations make it much easier to visualize stuff like this.